# how to identify which fragment is clicked in onMapReady method

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, fragment

i have an activity which have two fragment attach to it.Both of them show google map.[this is the xml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAJAu.png)
now i want to achieve is that i want to know which fragment is called in side onMapReady method

here i am setting the 2 fragments

```
 gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    gmap2 = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map2));
```

here i am setting getMapAsync for both of them

```
        gmap.getMapAsync(this);

    gmap2.getMapAsync(this);
```

now here i want to know which fragment map is clicked

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //here i want to know which fragment is clicked

}
```

Comment: Use different listener. Create 2 objects of OnMapClickListener

Comment: So there is no way without using 2 different   listeners?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 different Listeners like this:

```
 gmap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        }
    });
}

 gmap2.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We cant achieve it with just a single method?